# When using or crafting a Spellcasting item, do modifiers that apply to spellcasting apply?

Tags: magic-items, anima-beyond-fantasy, spellcasting

Specifically, I am interested in if the Power Boost power (from the Prometheum Exxet) could interact with an item that has the Spellcasting power (though there may be other cases where interactions could occur).  It is not immediately clear from the text.

There are two cases to consider:

1. A spellcaster with the modifier uses the item.
2. An item is created with the Spellcasting power *and* the other modifier.

I suspect there is no official ruling on this (as with most of my other questions, in fact), so I will accept subjective arguments.

Answer (score -2):

As a DM, it does not seem like much of a stretch for an item to benefit from its own upgrades. I can't find any official rulings on this either, so it seems mostly subjective. With that said, here's what I think:

1. I don't believe that the item should benefit from the casters power
   boost, as they are not the ones casting the spell — the artifact is.
2. The item should probably benefit from its own modifiers, because
   that is magic inherent to it.